# What comic has an angel who left heaven in a relationship with a single mother?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a comic that I skimmed in 2000, but the title and series eludes me. The only details that I remember are that it was about an angel who left heaven, and he was involved in a relationship with a single mother.

One scene depicted the mother preforming oral sex on him due to having her monthly cycle, and later she was washing her mouth and he wondered why she offered to do so if she did not like the taste. Later in the story, he realized his angelic origin and killed the mother and child.

It was written in English, in full color with fully detailed artwork.

Comment: What sort of comic? A comic book, a web comic? Was it in color? What language was it in?  What sort of art was it (super-detailed, stick figures, etc)?

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar to me. I want to say it's a Vertigo comic. Circa 2000... maybe Lucifer?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not Lucifer.  Most likely is under the Vertigo label, I almost want to say that I think it may have been written by Neil Gaiman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Murder Mysteries by Neil Gaiman and P. Craig Russell. It was originally a short story and then turned into a comic.

There is actually two murders, the one you remember and one at the start of the story where an angel is murdered in heaven.

In this story it was a human character that had oral sex with the woman and killed her. The angel who investigated the murder in heaven came down to Earth (kicked out of heaven? Can't remember) and told the human character about his investigation of the original murder.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_Mysteries